# Specific host file for interface with dnsmasq

Tags: debian, interface, dnsmasq

I use a VPN on an interface, e.g **tun0 (2.2.2.0/24)**, while the LAN network is on the interface **eth0 (1.1.1.0/24)**.

I use *dnsmasq* to route specific addresses to my LAN and these addresses have their VPN network counterparts which should link to the same host name which resides on the same machine which is also the DNS. *(The interfaces are firewalled so eth0 can't communicate with tun0 and viceversa)*

So we would have two host file like these:

**hosts.eth0:**

```
1.1.1.1 example.com
```

**hosts.tun0:**

```
2.2.2.1 example.com
```

I'm finding some difficulties to tell dnsmasq to use a specific host file for a specific interface without launching dnsmasq two times in a way similar to:

```
dnsmasq -I lo -i eth0 -H hosts.eth0
```

and its counterpart

```
dnsmasq -I lo -i tun0 -H hosts.tun0
```

This approach isn't very nice on a Debian 8 box and I think there must be a better way to achieve what I want to do.
What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this do what you're looking for?

> -y, --localise-queries
>
> Return answers to DNS queries from /etc/hosts which depend on the interface over which the query was received. If a name in /etc/hosts
>   has more than one address associated with it, and at least one of
>   those addresses is on the same subnet as the interface to which the
>   query was sent, then return only the address(es) on that subnet. This
>   allows for a server to have multiple addresses in /etc/hosts
>   corresponding to each of its interfaces, and hosts will get the
>   correct address based on which network they are attached to. Currently
>   this facility is limited to IPv4.